# how to find element asap, do not wait selenium pageloaded

Tags: python, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i want to use selenium to find element asap when the DOMcontentLoad

how can`findElement` execute do not wait until the page loaded?

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver'),
    By = webdriver.By,
    until = webdriver.until

;(async function main(){
    driver =await new webdriver.Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build()
    await driver.get('some url')//wait until it throw timeout error
    ele=await driver.findElement(By.id('username'))
    ele.sendKeys('xxx')
})()
```

i try to use

```
await driver.manage().setTimeouts({pageLoad:3e3,script:2e3})
```

but after catch errors, all promises are timeouted

environment

- nodejs
- "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1"
- chromedriver 73.0.3683.20

---

finally, my nodejs solution:

```
var {Options} = require('selenium-webdriver/chrome'),
    {Builder,By,until,Capabilities}=require('selenium-webdriver'),
    driver;
;(async function main(){
    driver =await new Builder()
        .withCapabilities(
            Options.chrome().setPageLoadStrategy('none')
        ).build()
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selenium web driver supports three page-load strategies.

**normal**

This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the full page loading (html content and subresources downloaded and parsed).

**eager**

This stategy causes Selenium to wait for the DOMContentLoaded event (html content downloaded and parsed only).

**none**

This strategy causes Selenium to return immediately after the initial page content is fully received (html content downloaded).

---

You have to set your page load strategy to `eager`. Although chrome doesn't support 'eager', you can set it to 'none'. Then you need to synchronize driver wait for some elements.

**Python**

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

option = Options()
option.set_capability("pageLoadStrategy","eager")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="chromedriver.exe",options=option)
```